# WCF - Array or Collection (are they both interoperable)?

Tags: arrays, wcf, collections, interop, wcf-interoperability

Basically, are they both interoperable or is it just the array that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both projected the same in the WSDL, so you can use one in the client and another in the server without problems. Both T[], Collection and List are considered "the same" as far as WCF is concerned.